# Job Company Page - User with 1 reputation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I have seen few company pages on SO Jobs and I like the section "Who you'll work with". This gives a person an opportunity before applying for a job to know people already working for that company.

But I have recently seen a company page which has 6 users listed on "Who you'll work with" section and only 3 of them have reputation > 1. I don't think this adds any values by merely listing the users no matter what their reputation/contribution is to SO.

I am not saying they should start contributing to SO, but just seeing a profile page with very minimal information is not adding any values according to me.

Comment: Well they may have 1 reputation at SO but a significant amount at another stack exchange site that might have an impact for the job they do.

Comment: Its hard to see where this user list comes fro, tbh.